# CQL SELECT query gets hanged while connecting to staging Cassandra servers?

Tags: c++, cassandra, cql, libcql

I have a DEV box from which I am trying to connect to my STAGING Cassandra servers on port 9042 as I am using a new binary protocol. I am running my C++ code from the DEV box using `libcql library` for Cassandra..

But somehow I guess, I am able to make a connection to my staging Cassandra servers on port 9042 as `Connected Successfully` gets printed out..

Below is the code I have in my header files -

```
static cql_client_t* client;
shared_future<cql_future_connection_t> connect_future;

const string server = "sc-host01.vip.slc.qa.host.com"; //"localhost";


//Open the connection
void connection_open() {
    connect_future = client->connect(server, 9042);

    cout<<"Connected Successfully"<< endl;
    connect_future.wait();
}

//Execute a Query
cql_result_t& execute_query(string query) {
    bool error = false;
    cql_result_t* result=NULL;
    try{
        if (!connect_future.get().error.is_err()) {
            cout << "query " << query << endl;
            shared_future<cql_future_result_t> future = client->query(query,CQL_CONSISTENCY_ONE);
            future.wait();
            error = future.get().error.is_err();
            result = &*future.get().result;
        } else{
            cout << "Query status... " << (!error ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
        }
    }catch (int e){
        cout << "An exception occurred when executing query. " << e << endl;
    }
    return *result;
}

#endif
```

And below is the code I have in `.cc file` which will try to make the connection by using the above class.. And then execute the query as well.

```
/**
 * This method will retrieve the data from Cassandra..
 * And then call print_rows method to print it out on the console
 */
void get_attributes(string id){
    try{

        // some code

        cout << "id " << id << endl;

        //Connection open
        connection_open();

        execute_query("USE profileks;");

        //this will give me the result back of the select query
        cql_result_t& result = execute_query("select * from profile_user where key ='"+id+"';");

        // and this is printing it out on the console
        print_rows(result);

        // some code
    } catch (int e){
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Now the problem that I am facing is it doesn't returns me any result back.. It gets hanged on the select query somehow -

This is what I see on my console -

```
id 1
Connected Successfully
query USE profileks;
query select record_name, record_value from user_data where user_id ='1';
```

And it gets hanged after that, meaning it is not returning my any result back... But the same code works fine for my local cassandra server. As soon as I changed the staging cassandra information to local machine, it starts working fine...

I also checked ports (9042) are opened fine.. Then why the query is getting hanged?

I am assuming, there might be some changes I need to make in `execute_query` method to make it work?

Cassandra Version that I am running on Staging servers is 1.2.9 and locally it is 1.2.8

**Update:-**

I did some research and this line is not returning me anything - meaning future.get is not working fine somehow..

```
result = &*future.get().result;
```

after it tries to execute my CQL Select query.. `USE profileks` works fine but only the CQL Select query gets hanged..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run the same query from CQLsh?
I think your query is timing maybe because of large number of rows returned, maybe if you add a limit X, it would help.
If you are meant to get all the data with a 'SELECT * FROM mycolumnfamily' you might want to review your data architecture. 
Have a look at the SELECT documentation http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#SELECT
Also from the docs 'When using a range, it is sometimes useful to limit the number of columns that can be returned as part of each row (since Cassandra is schemaless, it is not necessarily possible to determine ahead of time how many columns will be in the result set). To accomplish this, use the FIRST clause with an integer to specify an upper limit on the number of columns returned per row. The default limit is 10,000 columns.'

Comment: Yes from cqlsh, it works fine... As I mentioned in my question as well, it works fine for localhost cassandra cluster... And by the way, I only have two rows inside that table so it doesn't make sense to not come back...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something vaguely similar. future.get().result always had null pointers for the exact same code that worked elsewhere. I traced it down to a g++ command line option:

compile with "g++ -std=gnu++0x ..." and it fails
compile with "g++ ..." and it works